# Writing a very generic method

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have a method like this

```
void Foo(IMyInterface obj)
{

}
```

Now, sometimes in this method I want to do this

```
obj.A++;
```

and sometimes I want to do this

```
obj.B--;
```

The question is, how can I pass something into this method to allow this sort of thing in a generic way so that no matter what I pass in, it will get executed.  So, I'm looking for an Expression or a Func or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for an [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx):

```
static void Foo<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action) where T : IMyInterface
{
    action(obj);
}
```

Comment: `action` should be an `Action<IMyInterface>`.

Comment: Actually, it probably should be generic where `T : IMyInterface` since the caller will need the argument to match the real type so they can call their extra methods. Otherwise it could be a non-generic `Action`.